# Read Data in a nested Json

Tags: python, json

I have this very long json here: https://textup.fr/601885q4 and would like to read a data that is in one of the "payment_token_contract" specifically those with "id":1

My problem is that I don't get how to call the specific dictionary as they all have the same name. Is this even possible, I'm not used to manipulating such complex objects as I'm a beginner.

I would have tried something like:

```
["orders][x]["id":1]["base_price"]
```

with `x` being in a for loop that iterates through each "orders" present.

But I can't manage to put it all together. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop to iterate over the orders, you can check the value of the payment contract id and if its 1 then print the base price for that order

```py
import json

jdata = "yourjson"
jdict = json.loads(jdata)

for order in jdict["orders"]:
    if order['payment_token_contract']['id'] == 1:
        print(order["base_price"])
```

I have omited the json data as its to long but you can image jdata is the string of your json

**OUTPUT**

```
149000000000000000000
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! I had pretty much this idea but still struggled way too much on synthax, guess I need to learn the basics better :)